# How to set a file size limit on a self-hosted (AppSelfHostBase) Servicestack service (RequestStream)?

Tags: c#, .net-core, servicestack

A self-hosted service stack host using AppSelfHostBase has a service method:

```
public object Any(UploadImageRequest request)
{
     // Need to make sure the file is not too large!
}

[Route("/UploadImage")]
public class UploadImageRequest : IRequiresRequestStream
{
    public Stream RequestStream { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've actually found one possible way:

```
     public object Any(UploadImageRequest request)
     {
            if (Request.ContentLength > 10 * 1024 * 1024)
            {
                return new HttpResult($"Image too large!", HttpStatusCode.RequestEntityTooLarge);
            }
            ...
     }
```